# Enviado POST de text "<td>" via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

Boa tarde, tenho este código:

```
            <?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>

                <tr>
                    <td class="seis"><?php echo $row['seis']; ?></td>
                    <td class="ban"><?php echo $row['ban']; ?></td>
                    <td name="bon"><?php echo $row['bon']; ?></td>
                    <td name="qntd"><?php echo $row['quantidade']; ?></td>
                    <td name="pre"><?php echo "R$ " . $row['preco']; ?></td>
                    <td name="ven"><?php echo $row['Vendedor']; ?></td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <input name="comprar" id="comprar" value="Comprar" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"></input>                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

Ele faz uma tabela para cada coluna no BD. Eu preciso enviar estas informações (realizando um POST) do que está dentre os `<td>`. Tentei com este código:

```
     <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     // No click do botão de submit
     $('#comprar').click(function () {
         // Recebe os dados do formulário
         var valorTd = $('.seis').text();
         // Envia a requisição ajax
         $.ajax({
             url: "ajax/recebe_pedido.php", // Arquivo php que vai receber os dados
             data: { // Recebe os dados das td´s e passa em um json
             valorTd: valorTd,
             },
             global: false,
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "html",
             success: function (data) { // se tudo der certo mostra essa mensagem
                alert('Requisição realizada com sucesso!');
          },
        }).responseText;
    });
});
</script>
```

Mas ao clicar no botão **comprar**, todos os `<td>` estão sendo enviado, sendo que é pra enviar de acordo com a coluna que eu cliquei o botão **comprar**

Exemplo: `valorTd: 498401 498406 547874 547874 547874 547874 547874 547874 547874 547874`

Comment: Não ficou muito claro, mas... 1) seu `foreach` vai gerar vários td's com o mesmo valor no atributo `name`; 2) no jquery você faz referência à classe `$('.seis').text()` e deveria ser ao atributo `name`

Comment: No seu *input* você poderia criar um atributo referencial apontando para a `tr` e então pelo jquery você 'navega' pelos `td's` que precisa recuperar.

Comment: Tentei desta forma: `  var valorTd = $('#seis').text();
         var valorTd2 = $('#ban').text();
         // Envia a requisição ajax
         $.ajax({
             url: "ajax/recebe_pedido.php", // Arquivo php que vai receber os dados
             data: { // Recebe os dados das td´s e passa em um json
             valorTd: valorTd,
             valorTd2: valorTd2, ` Mas o POST vem vazio (eu alterei de class para name)

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que no seu foreach tenha uma coluna `id`, tente assim:

```
<?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="seis_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['seis']; ?></td>
        <td class="ban_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['ban']; ?></td>
        <td class="bon_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['bon']; ?></td>
        <td class="qntd_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['quantidade']; ?></td>
        <td class="pre_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo "R$ " . $row['preco']; ?></td>
        <td class="ven_<?=$row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Vendedor']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <input name="comprar" id="comprar" value="Comprar" class="comprar btn btn-success" type="submit" coluna="<?=$row['id']?>"></input>                   
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // No click do botão de submit
        $('.comprar').click(function () {
            var coluna = $(this).attr('coluna');
            // Recebe os dados do formulário
            var valorTd = $('.seis_'+coluna).text();
            // Envia a requisição ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/recebe_pedido.php", // Arquivo php que vai receber os dados
                data: { // Recebe os dados das td´s e passa em um json
                valorTd: valorTd,
            },
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) { // se tudo der certo mostra essa mensagem
                alert('Requisição realizada com sucesso!');
            },
        }).responseText;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas só o primeiro botão **Comprar** está enviando requisição, o resto não funciona

Comment: Sabe dizer por que isso acontece ?

Comment: Tente agora, referenciei uma classe ao invés do id do botão

Comment: Deu certo ? Caso sim, marque a resposta como resolvida